# Slow boot, how to program fsck to run like a cron job?

Tags: boot, fsck

Sometimes my web server crashes, and it may take hours to boot. I've been told `fsck` might be the culprit, because it can only be run during boot, only runs after X days and Y mounts, and if the server was up for a lot of time, on the next reboot it will for sure be slow.

So what can I do to fix this? I found about `tune2fs`. But I will need to coordinate that with a reboot cronjob? Say I do `tune2fs -i 1w /dev/sda1`. I'm afraid that if I set a cron to run after that date (which I can get with `-l`), on the following dates they will be out of sync, won't they?

Another thing that is not clear: after a crash, will fsck run anyway no matter what? Should it? Will it still be slow, even if it was run less than a week ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*tl;dr: Take a look at your system logs, or use something like [`bootlogd`](http://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd), this should show you where the slow down is occurring. My bet would be that it is not `fsck`.*

---

Firstly, `fsck` can run whenever, it doesn't have to run at boot. What you're probably referring to is that it can only run on an unmounted filesystem, and since `/` and other filesystems are mounted when the system is fully operational, that is the only possible time to run it on *those* filesystems.

`fsck` should not take hours to complete if it is merely doing a regular check, unless it actually finds inconsistencies in the filesystem and has to fix them (but even then, an hour sounds highly unlikely, even on a large filesystem with numerous inconsistencies). Take a look at your system logs, or use something like [`bootlogd`](http://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd), this should show you where the slow down is occurring. My bet would be that it is not `fsck`.

Filesystems can develop inconsistencies without any noticeable side effects, that's the purpose of the regular `fsck` checks regardless of whether the filesystem is marked dirty.

You cannot unmount your root filesystem whilst the system is running, as it will be in use, therefore you cannot run `fsck` on it, so there is no way to properly run a cron job to do it. It would be possible to force a `fsck` on a reboot on certain dates, and then reboot, but I don't really see the point. I don't really understand what you mean by being "out of sync".

After a crash, `fsck` will run on any dirty filesystems, that is, filesystems that were not cleanly unmounted. If your computer was to crash during normal operation, therefore, yes, `fsck` would run. If your computer crashed at the very final stage of shutdown, probably not, as the filesystems would not have been compromised.

Comment: "I don't really understand what you mean by being "out of sync"" I mean that if I set it to run 1w, then check the date and it says eg: Sun 20 05:00:00, then set a cron to reboot weekly starting on Sun 20 05:01, fsck will run on say Sun 20 05:01:02, and its next date will be Sun 27 05:01:02. I think that's how it works, and will get out of sync with the reboot cron.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper That filesystem flag to `fsck` is just that, a flag. It won't run weekly, it will be *flagged* to run weekly. That is, if you don't remount the filesystem, that week flag becomes irrelevant. `fsck` looks at the flag when it runs, but it will only run when the filesystem becomes available -- in your case, when you reboot.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I set it to run weekly and I also set a cron to reboot weekly.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper To avoid this issue altogether, you might want to use the `> /forcefsck` method, that is, create a file at `/forcefsck` and `fsck` will be forced to run on the next reboot. You could do that just before you reboot.

Comment: My guess was that if errors get acumulated on the disk, rebooting and running fsck frequently would prevent a terribly slow boot after a crash.

Comment: Ok I will try that and the bootlogd thing, thanks.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper If errors are regularly accumulating on the disk, then something is very wrong, and that should be dealt with separately. Regardless, `fsck` generally just doesn't take that long, even on disks with lots of inconsistencies.